# How can I add condition on v-model select ? vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selectedProvince"="level === 'province'"  v-model="selectedProvince"="level === 'city'">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['level'],
        data() {
            return {
                selectedProvince: '',
                selectedCity: '',
            };
        },
        ...
    };
</script>
```

Select provinces and cities have 1 select. It is differentiated by level. I want to add condition

If level = province, it will run v-model = "selectedProvince"

If level = city, it will run v-model = "selectedCity"

I tried like the code above, but from the writing, it seems it is still wrong

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside the issue that it seems odd that you would have two separate types of information in the same select, you would probably want to derive your values using computed values instead of what you're trying.

```
data(){
    return {
        selectedOption: null,
        level: "province"
    }
},
computed:{
    selectedProvice(){
        if (this.level === "province")
            return this.selectedOption
        else
            return null
    },
    selectedCity(){
        if (this.level === "city"
            return this.selectedOption
        else
            return null
    }
}
```

Then use `selectedOption` for your model.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selectedOption">
```